# Google Spreadsheet: loop through sheets stop working

Tags: google-apps-script

i've a function called when opening my spreadsheet that aim to loop trought all sheets, activate them and set cursor to the last modified cell (saved by another function) and, a the last re-select the last used sheet (saved as before by another function).
It worked fine for years, but suddenly stopped working.
Here is my code:

```
function onOpen()
{
  var timer = 2000;
  var proprieta = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  
  var lastSheet  = proprieta.getProperty("ultimo");
  var lastModifiedCell  = proprieta.getProperty(lastSheet);
  
  var applicazione = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fogli = applicazione.getSheets();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  for (var i=0; i < fogli.length; i++)
  {
    var attuale = fogli[i].getName();
    var ultimorange = proprieta.getProperty(attuale);
    
    applicazione.getSheetByName(attuale).getRange(ultimorange).activate();
    
    //ui.alert(attuale);
    //ui.alert(ultimorange);
    
    Utilities.sleep(timer);
  }
  
  applicazione.getSheetByName(lastSheet).getRange(lastModifiedCell).activate();
}
```

Doesn't return any error but the for loop is not selecting anymore sheet and range given.
If i enable the *ui.alert* the sheet name and range are displayed correctly.
The last selection ath the end, works correctly...i have no idea why it happens...
Is there anyone who can help me figure out what's wrong?
Thanks to anyone who will answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue. To prevent this from happening, you can use [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

### Your code:

```
function onOpen()
{
  var timer = 2000;
  var proprieta = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  
  var lastSheet  = proprieta.getProperty("ultimo");
  var lastModifiedCell  = proprieta.getProperty(lastSheet);
  
  var applicazione = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fogli = applicazione.getSheets();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  for (var i=0; i < fogli.length; i++)
  {
    var attuale = fogli[i].getName();
    var ultimorange = proprieta.getProperty(attuale);
    
    var range = applicazione.getSheetByName(attuale).getRange(ultimorange).activate();

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(timer);
  }

  applicazione.getSheetByName(lastSheet).getRange(lastModifiedCell).activate();
  ui.alert("Activation Done");
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Now it resumed working fine!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new but i found something recently (i come from excel scripts) :
getting a "range" and getting it's a1Notation are totally different.
Maybe your "ultimorange" (from "attuale") is a range and NOT the notation of the range.  It would make getRange(ultimorange) not working.

Comment: That is a valid observation. The [Properties Service documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) tells: _Data types that are not already strings are automatically converted to strings_. This means that a `Range` object cannot be saved in the `Properties` service, so chances are that `ultimorange` is an `A1Notation` text string.

Comment: I didn't know..but i already get the a1notation fortunately; in fact the last row of my code was working even if the for loop didn't.
Thanks!